# configurable sitemesh pattern in decorator.xml

Tags: design-patterns, configuration, decorator, sitemesh

Is it possible to add some configurable parameter in decorator.xml?
I need to do something like:

```
<decorator name="sample" page="sample.jsp">
      <pattern>/sample.${my.own.ext}</pattern>
</decorator>

<decorator name="example" page="example.jsp">
      <pattern>/example.${my.own.ext}</pattern>          
</decorator>
```

and in some config file mycfg.parameters put:

my.own.ext=myhtm

so it can be changed for other service

are there any solutions for this other then creating many decorator.xml files for other services?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to substitute the parameter at build time in the decorator.xml files.

In your maven pom.xml file you might define the property/resources like so:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <my.own.ext>html</my.own.ext>
  </properties>

  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <includes>
        <include>WEB-INF/decorator.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  <resources>
  ...
</project>
```

You can do [the same in Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) if you are not using maven.

Alternatively, you could use the method described in [Sitemesh Configuration: Medium Level, Assembly](https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh3/wiki/Design-Doc%3A-Configuration) to configure the decorator selector with a init-param/system property variable at run-time.  For example:

```
String extension = System.getProperty("extension");
javax.servlet.Filter filter = new SiteMeshFilterBuilder()
    .addDecoratorMapping("/sample." + extension, "/sample.jsp")
    .addDecoratorMapping("/example." + extension, "/example.jsp")
    .build();
```